# Moved to a home with a surround sound system, how do I set it up?

Tags: speakers

We recently moved to a home with a surround sound system, but we have absolutely no idea how to hook them up to our TV.

There are two front speakers. Their make/model are Yamaha NS-A636. Photos below:

[image: Yamaha NS-A636 front]

[image: Yamaha NS-A636 back]

There are also two back speakers. Their make/model are KLH 403A.

[image: KLH 403A Front]

[image: KLH 403A Back]

And then they left a panel in the middle of the room that looks like this:

[image: Panel]

There is no other equipment in the room.

How would I go about hooking this up to my TV? I have a LG OLED55B6P. Do I need to purchase any equipment? How would I hook up the equipment to the panel without knowing which connector goes to which speaker? Also, how do I ensure these are powered correctly?

One of the hookups (to the right front Yamaha speaker) also looks like it was cut. Is there a good way to figure out which connector goes to which wire in the speaker? I feel fairly comfortable with my soldering skills.

[image: Cut wires]

Comment: Before you get an A/V receiver  ( you need one ) i would suggest you join the forums over at https://www.avsforum.com/forum/index.php  There is a lot to learn when you are new to surround sound and they are helpful. They have good reviews and you can research before you buy.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, appliance operation is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it involves appliance operation.

Comment: Most systems nowadays have optical out. TVs, Bluray players, etc. Most amplifiers have an optical in and they then "drive" the speakers with power and signal. That's how you would go about hooking this up.

Answer (score 2):

go to Goodwill and get a receiver for like $15. Then hook up the speaker outputs to those speaker connections coming out of your wall in the 5th photo. You dont need to use a multimeter. The speaker wires on the receiver will be marked Left Front, Left Back, Right Front, Right Back, Middle, and Subwoofer. As you hook up the wires, listen and make sure you are connecting to the right terminals.

Answer (score 1):

### Surround Sound

One common configuration is called [5.1 surround sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5.1_surround_sound).  This configuration uses 5 speakers: two front (R and L), two rear (R and L), and one front center.  The '.1' corresponds to a subwoofer for increased low-end response.  (A similar configuration -- 5.2 -- supports two subwoofers for a stereo feel.)

[image: 5.1 configuration]

### Receivers

You'll need a 'surround sound receiver' from your favorite consumer electronics store.  Around 300 W should suffice -- most of the power supplies the sub-woofer.  5.2 receivers tend to be in the 700 W arena due to the double low-end.

Any decent receiver these days will allow you to adjust the volume for each channel so you can 'tune' the room.  You'll have to make sure the receiver can drive your particular set -- i.e. make sure it can drive your 4 Ohm KLH speakers.

Make sure any receiver you buy can interface with your TV.  It appears that your model can pretty much only output HDMI or optical audio.

You'll also need some speaker wire to connect your receiver with the wall connectors.  You can put your solder skills to the test and solder some banana jacks to one end of speaker wire, or look for ready-made cables.

### Speakers

All of your speakers are passive, meaning that they do not require their own power.  (Active speakers have their own integrated amplifier, and have input power inlets and switches.).

The front Yamaha with the cut wire looks like it can be repaired with simple wire nuts.  Make sure to connect the same colored wires together -- the white with the white and copper color with copper color.  Wrap some electrical tape over the nuts, too.

The easier way to tell which wall terminals go to which speaker is to hook up your amplifier (receiver) to each terminal pair (red and black) one-by-one.  Logically, the top-left pair corresponds to the front-left speaker, bottom-left pair to the rear-left speaker, and so on.  But one can never assume.

Answer (score 0):

Got a multimeter? Check for pairs that go to each speaker. With the exception of the one with the cut wire. Use the continuity setting on the meter and keep one lead on one terminal till you find its pair. Continue on till they all are found.
Those jacks are used with plugs like this...
https://www.primecables.ca/p-317581-high-quality-copper-speaker-banana-plugs-closed-screw-type-5-pairs-primecables
You will need a receiver or amplifier that can drive(power) the speakers.
Given that you currently have 4 speakers, a 5.1 surround setup will require a center speaker and sub to be added to the system setup.
https://m.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/product/denon-avrs540bt-5-2-channel-4k-ultra-hd-av-receiver/12468257
The links provided are just to show the connections used in regards to speakers.